# function declaration and assignment to a variable

Tags: python, lambda

I want to ask a question about how functions are assigned to variables.

I am a beginner in Python and studying functions.

Consider the following block of code from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_lambda_double):

```
def myfunc(n):
  return lambda a : a * n

mydoubler = myfunc(2)

print(mydoubler(11))
```

I know that a `lambda` is an anonymous function with only *one* expression that is evaluated and returned.

This is shown inside `myfunc(n)`:

```
return lambda a: a * n
```

`myfunc` takes in an argument, which in this case is 2, so any number `a` will be doubled.

However, I'm confused here.

In this line:

```
mydoubler = myfunc(2)
```

I thought we assign the result of `myfunc` to `mydoubler` but in the print statement:

```
print(mydoubler(11))
```

we are passing an argument `11` but we never specified the parameter `a` anywhere in the function declaration.

How does the python code know that `11` in this case inside the print statement is associated with `a`?

Answer (score 1):

The function created by `lambda a: a * n` is a *closure*. When the function is called as `mydoubler(11)`, it uses `11` as the value for `a`, and `2` (the value of `n` inside `myfunc` at the time `lambda a: a * n` was evaluated) as the value for `n`.

`mydoubler` behaves as if it were defined as

```
def mydoubler(a):
    return a * 2
```

You can see that the value `2` is stored in the function using a bit of digging:

```
>>> mydoubler.__closure__[0].cell_contents
2
```

(In fact, you can change that, though you would only do so if you want to make your code hopelessly complicated:

```
>>> mydoubler.__closure__[0].cell_contents = 3
>>> mydoubler(2)
6
```

)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you actually assigned the doubler-function to `mydoubler`:

```
mydoubler = myfunc(2)
```

There you also specified the parameter `a`, namly 2. So when you pass a number to the `mydoubler()` function, Python know that you already specified `n`

Answer (score 0):

The return value from `myfunc(2)` is equivalent to this lambda

```
lambda a: a * 2
```

That lambda takes 1 argument, and doubles it. When you call it, in this case by assigning it to the name `mydoubler`, whatever argument you pass to it is `a`, the one argument that the lambda accepts.

Equivalent code:

```
mydoubler = lambda a: a * 2
output = mydoubler(11) # returns 11 * 2
print(output) # prints 22
```

Comment: Not "exactly"; there's a difference between a hard-coded argument and the use of a value stored in the closure.